# UITabbar Appearance Chang in iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have added tabbar control to my view controller through the story board,
with following constraints..
[image]

As i required the selection indicator image for the selected item i am using following code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
super.viewDidLayoutSubviews();
viewForTab.setShadow(shadowColor: UIColor.gray.cgColor, shadowOffset:CGSize.init(width: 0.0, height: 3.0), shadowOpacity: 0.8, shadowRadius: 3.0)

tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = APPDELEGATE.getImageWithColorPosition(color: UIColor.themeSectionBackgroundColor, size: CGSize.init(width: viewForTab.frame.width/2, height: viewForTab.frame.height ), lineSize: CGSize.init(width: viewForTab.frame.width/2, height: 1.5))

}
```

It get perfect effect in iPhone but in ipad the ui get ugly, 
As you can see in below image, **Login and Register Text are not aligned** center and also the indicator put the **space from left side** of uitabbar item but in iphone it works perfectly.

Cant identify the issue..

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make class of UITabBar and give class of UITabBar from Stroyboard

```
class TabBar: UITabBar {

    override var traitCollection: UITraitCollection {
        guard UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad else {
            return super.traitCollection
        }

        return UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .compact)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Awesom bro!! thanks a lot :) Perfectly work as i want

Comment: working perfect in ipad but when change the orientation to landscape same as above layout not display proper